# Issue with .each() who return (nbr of objects x value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, each

I'm struggling with a issue populating a DropDown menu with an array.

My array, stored in an external json files is in the following format :

```
[{"name":"value_A", "other":"value_A1"}, {"name":"value_B1"}, {"name":"value_C"} ]
```

In order to use these data, I first push them in a array, then try to push them in a drop down menu.
My jQuery looks like the foolwoing :

```
function loadData() {

    $.getJSON(database, function (data) {

        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            myNewArray.push(
            {
                "name":data[i].name                 
            })

            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $("#myDiv").append('<option>' + data[i].name + '</option>')
            });
        };  
    });
}
```

It works "well" as dat go to my drop down menu, but it iterate all the data as the same amount of object.

For example, I f I got 10 objets in my array, it return 10 times the whole values asked
How to "stop" the iteration after query deliver the selected

```
[{"name":"value_A", "other":"value_A1"}, {"name":"value_B"}, {"name":"value_C"} ]
```

will return in a console :

value_A
value_B
value_C
value_A
value_B
value_C
value_A
value_B
value_C

I think I'm not so far for the good code, but after testing lot of combination, I can't solve it withou your help.

Thanks for any advise on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `$.each()` inside a `for` loop, so it creates a double iteration causing same elements to be added multiple times.

Only one of `$.each()` or the `for` loop is required

```
function loadData() {
    $.getJSON(database, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            myNewArray.push({
                "name": item.name
            })

            $("#myDiv").append('<option>' + item.name + '</option>')
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun it makes sense and teach me how to deal with .each or for!